# How can I pass a string through an inner class without finalizing it

Tags: android, listview, parameter-passing, listviewitem, inner-classes

I have implemented a ListView and want the OnClickListener to use the long id parameter (ie. which item from the list was clicked) to index the String[] that I am populating the list from, so that I can pass that String ie. the text of the specific item I clicked. I would make it final but that would be an issue as I need to repopulate this list later on in the lifecycle of the program (which you might say can't be done with a string, I will probably switch to a StringBuilder[] but if anyone has advice on this part feel free). I hope this is not confusing, to give some elaboration on what I am doing, I am populating a ListView from a String[] gathered from a mysql database and then I am going to later sort the list based on proximity (obtained from GPS position) so because the id for the listitem will be different for each person I am going to pass the text string that makes up the item in the list that was clicked on, so using item id alone is not feasible, because the item id for an individual list (that has been re-sorted) will be useless to the server. Can anyone advise me on how to make this possible or a potential work around?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use OnClickListener with a ListView. Use AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.
When you override its onItemSelected (AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id)
method, you get the ListView, the View that was clicked on in the list, its position and its id as parameters. If the list is just TextViews, like with a normal ArrayAdapter, you can just use view.getText().toString() to get the String out.

Comment: thanks, also I realized that I can actually replace the same string, I was confused because of the fact that I had read that the String class is immutable, but I just saw some code where they basically assigned a String and then used the .replace method and assigned the return result to the same string, so it looks like that should not be a problem for me either, i assume this is actually re-assigning the address that the string points to on the heap, is this correct?

Comment: Yes. Immutable is not the same as final. Immutable means that you cannot change the characters of the String- there is no insert character, delete character, add character etc. method. If the String class has methods that look like they are doing this, they are in fact creating a new String and reassigning the address.

Comment: hey I see what you mean about using view.getText().toString() but why can't I use this with OnClickListener, since it also gets passed a view in the OnItemClick constructor?

Comment: It can cause bugs with the ListView, OnItemClick is the proper way. Plus you get item position with it which you may need (it will presumably correspond with the index of the String in your array)

Comment: Did you mean that OnItemSelected is the proper way?

Comment: So as I understand it I can't use the ListView as I need to override the OnItemSelected method, so I need to create an adapter that extends activity and implements AdapterView, named something like SpecialAdapter then create an instance in the activity I am using it in and call the .OnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelected(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id){call Intent for new activity} then in the new activity I should use view.getText().toString(); method?

Comment: No, just make a custom OnItemSelectedListener or OnItemClickListener( both classes exist) and attach it to your listview using the ListView method setOnItemClickListener/setOnItemSelectedListener. They are both inner classes to the AdapterView class- in the same way as the more standard listeners are inner classes of the View class.

Comment: I added i.putExtra("deal", ((TextView) view).getText().toString()); to my OnItemClickListener before the startActivityForResult was called and inside the new activity onCreate method I added dealId = getIntent().getDataString(); this returns no errors, so I tried toasting it and got a null string, I also verified that it is not the toast method, do I need to wrap this in a bundle and then add that as an extra? btw my ListView Item contains text

Comment: What if OnItemClickListener returns a parent of your TextView therefore you need to access its first child for get the text?

Comment: could you give me an example of accessing the child?

Comment: SOLUTION           I didn't figure out how to access the child but I was able to create a bundle using Bundle bundle = new Bundle(); and the use bundle.putString("dealid",((TextView) view).getText().toString()); method to add the string to the bundle, the I used the intent "i" to add the bundle to the intent via i.putExtra("somebundle", bundle); and then in the activity called I retrieved the string via Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String dealId = bundle.getString("deal");